# Best way to wait for two events in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a class that have a internal queue and a server connection object. When an item is pushed to the queue, the connection is created, and the item is processed, the connection is destroyed, and then the loop waits for next item in the queue.

I want to, after connection is created, mantain created for X seconds/minutes, for the case of some new item is pushed, I dont have to re-create and re-authenticate the connection. Here a sample:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.Generics.Collections, System.Threading;

type
  TConn = class
  public
    procedure Authenticate;
  end;

  TMyClass = class
  private
    FQueue: TThreadedQueue<TProc<TConn>>;
    FTask: ITask;
    procedure Start;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Push(Proc: TProc<TConn>);
  end;

{ TConn }

procedure TConn.Authenticate;
begin

end;

{ TMyClass }

constructor TMyClass.Create;
begin
  FQueue := TThreadedQueue<TProc<TConn>>.Create;
  Start;
end;

destructor TMyClass.Destroy;
begin
  FQueue.DoShutDown;
  FQueue.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyClass.Push(Proc: TProc<TConn>);
begin
  FQueue.PushItem(Proc);
end;

procedure TMyClass.Start;
var
  Proc: TProc<TConn>;
  Conn: TConn;
begin
  FTask := TTask.Run(procedure
  begin
    while not FQueue.Shutdown or (FQueue.QueueSize > 0) do
    begin
      //Blocked by internal TMonitor, released when DoShutdown is called or PushItem
      FQueue.PopItem(Proc);

      if FQueue.ShutDown then
        Exit;

      Conn := TConn.Create;
      Conn.Authenticate;
      Proc(Conn);
      Conn.Free;
    end;
  end);
end;

var
  MyClass: TMyClass;
begin
  try
    MyClass := TMyClass.Create;
    MyClass.Push(procedure(AParam: TConn)
    begin
      //use conn
    end);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

In the call of `Conn.Free` I want to wait, and leave it created for some time. If the X seconds/minutes timeout is reached, then connection would be destroyed, and re-created in next item.

Is a timer the best approach here? I dont like to use timers, but it makes sense in this case, I think.

I could use the timeout of TThreadedQueue, but the timeout is setted in the create of the object, and used in the wait of `PopItem`. I wanted to wait only of connection is created, if there is no connection, it makes no sense to have this timeout. If timeout of TThreadedQueue was available in a prop, I could set it when creating the conn, and then, when destroyed, go back to infinite. But thats no the case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Connection pooling is often used in such situations. A separate thread keeps connections alive and manages the pool. Other threads get and return connections to the pool as needed.

Comment: In this case, the connection is with the application server. In server, there is the connection pool to the database. Here in the client I just have one connection to the server. There is the default connection (used by main thread), I want to implement this second background connection

Comment: @RodrigoCaetano you already know the concept of pooling and caching, so what is stopping you from doing the same here? Simply make the connection object be a global/member variable not a local variable, and put a timer next to it. If the object is not created, create it. Otherwise, if the timer hasn't elapsed yet, reuse the object. Otherwise, destroy and recreate the object. When the Proc is finished, reset the timer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau connection already is a class var in a singleton (in original code). What you described is the original idea of using timer. I just have not a very good experience using timers, so I try not to use it. My question is if there is another way around, or if the timer really is the best option here

Comment: @RemyLebeau  So, according to your answer, a timer really is the best approach.

Comment: @RodrigoCaetano It doesn't necessarily have to be an *actual* timer. Something like [`TStopWatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch) would suffice. Just something that track how much time has passed since the last time the connection was used. Though, I would suggest using an actual timer or thread to monitor that connection and destroy it if it sits unused for awhile.